# Handover Promise response to variable

Tags: java, kotlin, asynchronous, promise, axios

This is my first time of trying to use promise on kotlin

in javascript i can simple do this

```
const val = promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // after response
     resole(res)
    
   // if exception
   reject(with erro)
})
```

then am going to be able to access my response vals on the val constant.

I did similar thing with kotlin but i can't get to return the expected response to the val and i have been trying a lot

```
 fun promisMe(url: String): QuizFeed {

    val promise = Promise<QuizFeed, String> {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        val client = OkHttpClient();

        val requested: Unit = client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                reject(e.toString());
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body: String? = response.body?.string();
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val homeFeed: QuizFeed = gson.fromJson(body, QuizFeed::class.java)
                resolve(homeFeed)
            }
        });
    }

    return promise.onResolve { it.results }

}
```

I would appreciate for the help i really need to get this done

Comment: am using shopify promise

Comment: https://github.com/Shopify/promise-kotlin

Comment: `Promise#onResolve` returns `Promise`, [see here](https://github.com/Shopify/promise-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/shopify/promises/PromiseSideEffect.kt#L51-L56). I'd suggest use Coroutines if you want to return the result directly as a function return, and want to propagate the error as throw(ed) and handled by function caller.